# Efficient countByValue of each column Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to find countByValues of each column in my data. I can find countByValue() for each column (e.g. 2 columns now) in basic batch RDD as fallows:

```
scala> val double = sc.textFile("double.csv") 
scala> val counts = sc.parallelize((0 to 1).map(index => {
     double.map(x=> { val token = x.split(",")
     (math.round(token(index).toDouble))
     }).countByValue()
     }))
scala> counts.take(2)
res20: Array[scala.collection.Map[Long,Long]] = Array(Map(2 -> 5, 1 -> 5), Map(4 -> 5, 5 -> 5))
```

Now I want to perform same with DStreams. I have windowedDStream and want to countByValue on each column. My data has 50 columns. I have done it as fallows:

```
val windowedDStream = myDStream.window(Seconds(2), Seconds(2)).cache()  
ssc.sparkContext.parallelize((0 to 49).map(index=> {
val counts = windowedDStream.map(x=> { val token = x.split(",")
                                (math.round(token(index).toDouble))
                                }).countByValue()
counts.print()                                          
}))                                                
val topCounts = counts.map . . . .  will not work
```

I get correct results with this, the only issue is that I want to apply more operations on counts and it's not available outside map.

Comment: Why do you do `parallelize`? What good does a 2 (or 50) element RDD do?

Comment: I am doing parallelize to process all the columns in parallel. I can use a simple loop, but then i believe it will be less efficient. There are 50 column and each column is independent. I can do topCounts() just after .countByValue but it makes the application slow. Format is like Time, sensor1, sensor2 . . . . . . sensor50. This is not real stream but file read as DStream. I dont need on time so we can do it from 1 to 49.

Comment: Why do you use streams if the input is not a stream?

Comment: yes a good question. I use streams because it has applications in real life problem. Actually my data is eeg data. Although it is in csv file format now but later the work can be used to process eeg data at real time.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand what `parallelize` does. You think when you give it a Seq of two elements, those two elements will be calculated in parallel. That it not the case and it would be impossible for it to be the case.

What `parallelize` actually does is it creates an RDD from the Seq that you provided.

To try to illuminate this, consider that this:

```
val countsRDD = sc.parallelize((0 to 1).map { index =>
  double.map { x =>
    val token = x.split(",")
    math.round(token(index).toDouble)
  }.countByValue()
})
```

Is equal to this:

```
val counts = (0 to 1).map { index =>
  double.map { x =>
    val token = x.split(",")
    math.round(token(index).toDouble)
  }.countByValue()
}
val countsRDD = sc.parallelize(counts)
```

By the time `parallelize` runs, the work has already been performed. `parallelize` cannot retroactively make it so that the calculation happened in parallel.

The solution to your problem is to not use `parallelize`. It is entirely pointless.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel I go it. But is there a way to apply same operations on multiple columns of RDD. I know one can use DataFrames but if I don't want to use DataFrames, what are other options.

Comment: Just do the simple loop. There is nothing to be gained by parallelizing the loop. Even if you process one column at a time, that column is broken up and the pieces processed in parallel. So you don't need to parallelize the loop to use all the available cores.